# Laravel how to pass multiple values in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a new row in my table using laravel 5.2 queries.

My table "answers" has 5 columns-> `answer_id (auto_inc), people_id(sames as Auth::id), question_id('Integer'), answer(input field), created_at(timestamp())`

answercontroller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class answerController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Requests\answerAddRequest $request)
    {
        Auth::user()->questions('question_id')->answers()->create($request->all());
    }
}
```

answers model class

```
class answers extends Model
{
    protected $table='answers';
    protected $fillable='answer';
    protected $primaryKey='answer_id';
    public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {}
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\questions','people_id');
    }
}
```

I'm unable to add a new row in answers table as I'm not able to understand how can I pass the question_id in the table

questions model class

```
class questions extends Model
{
    protected $table='questions';
    protected $primaryKey='question_id';
    protected $fillable = [
       'question', 'created_at','details'
    ];
    //protected $hidden=['question_id'];
    public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {}
    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\answers','answer_id');
    }
    public function scopefetchQuestions($query) {
        return $query->select('question','question_id')->where('people_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
    }
}
```

It's throwing this error with the current code:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::answers()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you actually putting a question_id in questions('question_id') or do you just have that as a string?

Comment: no 'question_id' is a column in 'questions' table

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
class answerController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Requests\answerAddRequest $request)
    {
        $answer = App\Answer::create($request->all());
        Auth::user()->questions()->where('question_id', $request->get('question_id'))->first()->answers()->save($answer);
    }
}
```

Also add foreign keys to the `$fillable` array
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: The query worked but now `Auth::user()` is not returning any "id", im getting '0' for people_id

Comment: User has just `id`, if you want to change it you need to change `protected $primaryKey` variable, but in this case old user data will be corrupted and you will need to change local and foreign keys for for each relationship method that interact with the User model. Would be better to remain just `id`